# How to block submission until form gets validated using jQuery Validate plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i have a search button on my form, when i hit on it, the onclick attribute activate and jump it into function which i have mentioned on onclick
this is my button,
`<input style="float:right;" type="submit" onclick="getData('search')" id="search" class="btn btn-success" name="searchbtn" value="Search">`

i want when i hit on search button first form validate then go to that function but i don't know why before validating it directly goes to that function

```
$('#myForm').validate({
    onclick:false,
        rules:{
                name:"required",
                dob:"required",
                email:{
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                age:{
                    required: true,
                    number: true,
                    minlength:2,
                    maxlength:2
                }
              },
              messages:{
              name: "Please Enter Name",
              email: "Please Enter valid Email",
              number: "Please Enter Only Digits",
              min_length:"Please Enter Minimum 2 Digit",
              max_length:"Please Enter Maximum 2 Digit"
              }
        });
```

this is my jquery validation code.

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
                Name:<p><input id="name_search" class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" required></p>
                Date of Birth:<p><input class="form-control" id="dob_search" type="text" name="dob" placeholder="dd/mm/yy" required></p>
                Sex:<p> <select id="sex_search" name="sex" class="form-control">
                    <option value="Male">Male</option>
                    <option value="Female">Female</option>
                            </select></p>
                Email:<p><input id="mail_search" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required></p>
                Age: <p><input id="age_search" class="form-control" type="text" name="age" placeholder="Age" required></p><br/>
                <input style="float:right;" type="submit" onclick="getData('search')" id="search" class="btn btn-success" name="searchbtn" value="Search"></form>
```

this is my form

Comment: $("#myform").validate({
  onsubmit: false
});

Comment: everything needed is in documentation, just read: https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your validation plugin might not be loaded. Check the console for errors.

Also `getData('search')` should be called after validation is passed.

And remove `onclick="getData('search')"`from

```
<input style="float:right;" type="submit" onclick="getData('search')" id="search" class="btn btn-success" name="searchbtn" value="Search">
```

Try adding

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
        getData('search');
      }:
```

in :

```
$("#myform").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    getData('search');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

removing the onclick attribute from html markup and calling the function after confirming your form's validity would do, like:

```
$('#myForm').validate({
    ....
});

$('#search').click(function() {
    //check if form is valid
    if ( $('#myform').valid() ) {
        //call the function
        getData('search');
    }
});
```